# Error while uploading file on Net4India

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, image

I am new in asp.net. I am trying to upload an image from sub-directory to root. It works fine while debugging the code. But when i upload on IIS it gives an

```
Access to the path 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\APBooksHosting\HomeImage\Desert.jpg' is denied.
```

My directory structure :

-ROOT-books-users-create-HomePage.aspx (Page from where i try to upload an file)

-ROOT-HomeImage ("It is the folder where i want to upload an file")

I am using this code to upload an file

```
namespace WebApplication1.books.users.Create
{
 public partial class Homeimage : System.Web.UI.Page
 {

    public void upload image()
    {
       if (homeimguploader.HasFile)
       {


                String path = Server.MapPath("~/HomeImage/");
                String ext = Path.GetExtension(homeimguploader.FileName);

                if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".png" || ext == ".gif")
                {

                    homeimguploader.SaveAs(path + homeimguploader.FileName);
                    homeimage = homeimguploader.FileName;
                }
       }
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For permission issue you can use below code:

```
// Get full permissons 
var permission = new FileIOPermission(FileIOPermissionAccess.Write, "Full Physical Path Here");
var permissionSet = new PermissionSet(PermissionState.None);
permissionSet.AddPermission(permission);
if (permissionSet.IsSubsetOf(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.PermissionSet))
{
      //your code here
}
```

Comment: i am using string path = Server.MapPath("/homeimage/"); . So should i put this path variable at the place of "Full Physical Path" ?. Dear your code is not working.

Comment: i try this path is working fine in my local system after published in IIS but it is not working on NET4India hosting. So it is possible might be problem from Net4India ?

Comment: Yes,them you will need to ask your hosting provider.

Comment: You can post the answer if its helpful

Comment: Actually problem is solved by NET4India (Hosting Provider). They provide me full access for my required folders